# Square root property to solve quadratic equation: $3(x-4)^2=15$ I get $\sqrt{21}$ but solution is $4+-\sqrt{5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to solve for x using square root property:

$3(x-4)^2=15$

The textbook solution is $4+-\sqrt{5}$ and I am unable to arrive at this. I arrived at $\sqrt{21}$

Here is my working:

$3(x-4)^2=15$

$(x-4)^2=5$ # divide both sides by factor 3

$x^2-16=5$ # multiply out $(x-4)^2$

$x^2 = 21$

$x=\sqrt{21}$

How can I arrive at $x=4+-\sqrt{5}$ # not sure syntax for 'plus or minus' symbol here, just used +-

Comment: $(x-4)^2$ isn't $x^2-16$.

Comment: To obtain $\pm$, type `$\pm$`.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have$(x-4)^2 = 5$

Taking sqrt on both sides,

$$x-4 = \pm\sqrt5$$
$$x = 4 \pm\sqrt5$$
That's it!

Comment: Hi, thanks but I don't follow because I don't see how you handled the squared term. $(x-4)^2=5$ and then you went from there to just $x-4=\pm5$?

Comment: $$x-4=\pm\sqrt{5}$$ that's it!

Comment: The square of(x+4) is 5. So if we take sqrt. of both sides we have +/-(x - 4) = sqrt(5).

Comment: Then just transfer the +- sign to right hand side

Comment: Two of the three occurrences of $5$ in this answer should have been $\sqrt5$.

Comment: Pardon, I didn't understand.

Comment: $x-4=\pm\sqrt5$ and $x=4\pm\sqrt5$.

Comment: Oh! I missed the sqrt. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying we get
$$(x-4)^2=5$$ and expanding $$x^2-8x+11=0$$ so $$x_{1,2}=4\pm \sqrt{16-11}$$

Comment: What's the opposite of "completing the square"?

Comment: The opposite: destroying the square (joke)

Comment: Having learned the quadratic formula, we use it, no matter what.

Comment: Ok, the main thing is your problem is solved now!